# Guice: how to get more than one @Provides for a type?

Tags: java, hibernate, guice

I'm working on a project and trying to bring two different 'data service' modules together into a web app (currently, the app is a desktop Swing app).

Each module has its own Guice (private) module.  Each Guice module contains:

```
@Provides
@Inject
protected JPQLQuery provideJPQLQuery(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new JPAQuery(entityManager);
}
```

This is used later in the constructor of the classes that look things up from the db:

```
@Inject
public SomeClassThatLooksObjectsUpFromDatabase(Provider<JPQLQuery> queryProvider) {
    this.queryProvider = queryProvider;
}
```

The 'queryProvider' is then able to execute queries.

Now, this works fine when only one of the Guice modules is installed, but once both are installed, I (predictably) get this error:

```
Unable to create binding for com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLQuery.  It was already configured on one or more child injectors or private modules
bound at ServiceOneGuiceModule.provideJPQLQuery()
bound at ServiceTwoGuiceModule.provideJPQLQuery()
```

Now, I understand why this is broken -- I'm saying that there's two Providers for the type JPQLQuery and Guice doesn't know which one to use.

Is there any way I can get Guice to separate these Providers?  I would like to do this because each module has its own properly-configured Hibernate entities, and each has its own unique datasource (multiple databases in this project).

Ideally, it would involve something like somehow naming these providers and injecting them by their name (e.g. I could separately inject "ServiceOneJPQLQueryProvider" and "ServiceTwoJPQLQueryProvider"), but I haven't found any way of achieving anything like this.

(I suppose an alternative is to somehow configure Hibernate so it has all the different datasources it needs and then I'd only need one Provider for my queries, possibly, but that seems like a lot more work than what I'm describing above)

Comment: Also, using the @Named annotation on provideJPQLQuery doesn't seem to work, because it applies the name to JPQLQuery, and not the Provider...

Comment: (or I may just be doing it wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look [binding annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations), they're used to solve just the problem you've got.

They're recommended over using *@Named* because they are type-safe and will produce compilation errors and not runtime errors if you misspell them.

In short:

ServiceOne.java:

```
@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ServiceOne {}
```

ServiceTwo.java:

```
@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ServiceTwo {}
```

ServiceOneModule.java:

```
@Provides
@ServiceOne
@Inject
protected JPQLQuery provideJPQLQuery(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new JPAQuery(entityManager);
}
```

SomeClass.java:

```
@Inject
public SomeClassThatLooksObjectsUpFromDatabase(@ServiceOne Provider<JPQLQuery> queryProvider) {
    this.queryProvider = queryProvider;
}
```

Comment: Accepted for the extra type safety.

Additionally, some of the problems I encountered getting this to work were caused by there being more Guice modules buried in the source that I initially didn't realize were there (big project!) -- so while I thought I was giving a name to some injected component, I was naming it in another module that the injected class wasn't using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're incorrect about `@Named` because providers are ubiquitous in Guice - in fact, when you create a binding like `bind(...).to(...)` or any other non-provider binding you're implicitly creating a provider. And it is just a shortcut for injecting providers when you inject objects directly - providers injection and direct injection are interchangeable in Guice (when you are not using special scopes like `RequestScoped`, but this is more like implementation detail of this shortcut). For example, even if you created `@Provides` method for `JPQLQuery`, you still can inject it directly, without a provider:

```
@Inject
public SomeClass(JPQLQuery query) {
    ...
}
```

Which approach to use depends on your requirements (do you need several *fresh* instances of `JPQLQuery` inside `SomeClass` methods?) and scopes in use (e.g. when scope of `SomeClass` is wider than that of `JPQLQuery` - for example, when `SomeClass` is singleton, and `JPQLQuery` is request scoped - sometimes provider usage is mandatory).

You're not getting what you want with `@Named` yet because you create `@Named` binding with `@Provides`, but still inject `Provider<...>` without annotation. It won't work because binding key consists both of injected type and (possibly absent) binding annotation, so if you have only bindings with assigned annotation but inject provider or type without annotation, Guice will fail. You should put `@Named` annotation onto the constructor parameter as well:

```
@Inject
public SomeClass(@Named("ServiceOne") Provider<JPQLQuery> queryProvider) {
    ...
}
```

This way it should work.

BTW, I strongly recommend against `@Named`. You'd better create separate binding annotation for each of your distinct binding for the same class, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations). With custom annotations you won't have a chance to make a mistake in binding name when you inject it.

Also there is more advanced machinery for manipulating similar bindings. It is called [private modules](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html). However, you should rarely need it. It could be needed, for example, to create trees of objects which differ only in few bindings. This does not seem to be your case - binding annotations are your way to go.